# Assume that $G$ is a group with a subgroup $H$ s.t. $|H|=6, [G:H]> 4$, and $|G| < 50$. What are the possibilities for $|G|$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-verification, order-theory

> Assume that $G$ is a group with a subgroup $H$ s.t. $|H|=6, [G:H]> 4$, and $|G| < 50$. What are the possibilities for $|G|$?

$|G|$ has to be a multiple of $6$ so either $12, 18, 24, 30, 36, 42$ or $48.$ But since $[G:H]$ has to be greater than $4$, that only leaves $|G|$ to be $30,36,42$, and $48$. Does this seem right?

Follow up question? What if $[G:H]>3, |G|<45$, and $|H|>10$ Would $|G|$ only be able to be $44$?

Comment: Looks right to me.

Comment: If $|G|\lt 45$ and $|H|\gt 40$, and $[G:H]\gt 3$, then no such group exists.

Comment: If, on the other hand, you mean $[G:H]\gt 3$, $|G|\lt 45$, and $|G|\gt 40$, then the only possible value (with $|H|=6$) would be $42$, not $44$.

Comment: I made a typo and have corrected it |H|>10

Comment: After the correction, we have $|H| \geq 11$ and $|G:H| \geq 4$ so $|G| = |G:H||H| \geq 44$. Since also $|G| < 45$ this forces $|G| = 44$ as you said.

Comment: Please don't forget to accept answers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you're right.

According to [this comment of @Bungo's](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3406101/assume-that-g-is-a-group-with-a-subgroup-h-s-t-h-6-gh-4-and-g/3406165#comment7006077_3406101), if $\lvert H\rvert>10$ and  $[G:H]>3$, then $\lvert G\rvert=44$ by $|G|=[G:H]|H|$ and $|G|<45$.